# How can I set specific parameters in multiple query params in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to ask how can I set specific parameters for the multiple query params in HttpRequest using angular Js, 
so I have this code in my service

```
return this.httpClient.request<any>('get',`${this.basePath}/class/classes/`,
            {
                params: queryParameters,
                withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
                headers: headers,
                observe: observe,
                reportProgress: reportProgress
            }
        );

dataClassList(klass_id?: string, klass__title?: string, recurrence?: string)
```

and here's I call my service in ts files.

```
async filterSchedule(recurrence) {
    let result = await this.classService.dataClassList(recurrence.toString()).toPromise();
      console.log(result)
    }
```

I run function in ngOnit()

```
async ngOnInit() {
let id = this.<data>.id
this.filterSchedule(id);
```

}

this part

```
this.classService.dataClassList(**recurrence.toString()**).toPromise();
```

is calling the HttpRequest Service and put the recurrence id as a **recurrence** parameters value, but its always send the **klass_id** parameters not **recurrence** parameters

the expected behaviour is the code is sending a Get method and filter the data with **recurrence** parameters, but what I have now is the Get Method always filtering the data using **klass_id**.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Can you post the HTTP code you are using and where you are not being able to put multiple query params?

Comment: Ive edited my question, can you check?

Comment: Can you add the actual call that does the HttpRequest?

Comment: edited again, please take a look if its clear enough

Comment: @matadantelinga 1) why are you converting observables to promises? 2) You haven't included enough code to clearly demonstrate the problem. If you have a problem with setting http request properties, it should be easy to see a full audit trail of where they come from. Your http call doesn't even show the containing function's arguments, and it's impossible to see where `queryParameters` comes from.